# Where smart contracts are technically saved in the ETH blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

i have a few question about the "location" of the smart contracts.
I read articles about blockchain and development of smart contracts, but it is still not clear to me where these contracts are saved.So:
Where they saved?
Are they saved in the nodes?
Is there some sort of db where all smart contracts are saved in?

Thank you in adavance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for Ethereum or Quorum smart contracts are stored on every node in the network. And you can successfully use their view methods even if the node is offline - the only thing in this case you will see the data state at the time of the last synchronization of your node with the network.